# Json decode "Trying to get property of non-object" ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, error-handling

After some hours dealing with it, i'll be specific.

I'm trying to pass data from a table on angular (view), to the controller, the controller call to a factory and it last make an http request to a .php file.

It isn't so hard as it seems.

This is the error i'm getting
}

> Trying to get property of non-object on line 6

It's my .php file (to get a simple select query)

```
    // Including database connections
require_once '../../db/database_connections.php';
// Fetching and decoding the inserted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$query = "SELECT * from repartidor WHERE id_repartidor = '$data->codigo'"; //THIS is **line 6**
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$arr = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$arr[0] = $row;

// Return json array containing data from the databasecon
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr[0]);
?>
```

However, after debugging it for a while, the query and the response of the .php file does work (i prove it replacing the '$data->codigo' with the value).

I think the problem is that the data is not reaching or is incorrectly being decoded.

Factory code:

```
obtenerItem: function(item){
        return $http.post("http://localhost/sgzena/php/repartidor/repDetail.php", item);
    } //THERE is an update
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.actualizarItem = function (item) {
            repartidorFactory.obtenerItem(item) //aca iba ID
            .then(function (response) {
                var modal = abrirModal(response.data);
                modal.result.then(function(result) {
                    guardarRepartidor(result);
                }); 
            });
        }
```

View code:

```
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cod.</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Telefono</th>
                    <th>
                        <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="Acciones"></em>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="item in repartidores">
                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                    <td>{{item.id_repartidor}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.telefono}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-edit " tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip="Editar Repartidor" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="actualizarItem(item)"></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash " tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip="Eliminar Repartidor" ng-click="eliminarItem(item)"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: You will need to make a `POST` request in order to populate the request body for the `php://input` stream to read. You are making a `GET` request; these do not have request bodies. Also, you're calling [`$http.get()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) incorrectly anyway; the 2nd argument is `config`. Just switch to `$http.post()`

Comment: Also, please consider using a prepared statement to bind user-supplied parameters to your queries. See http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Phil at first thanks for answering. I've switched to `$http.post()`, however, it doesn't work. Excuse me if i do not understand very well, i'm newbie at angularJS. 
Should i change something on the .php file too?

Comment: Please update the code in your question to reflect the current state. Also please clearly point out which is line #6

Comment: Code updated. I'm sorry

Comment: Are there any other errors in your browser console? What URL are you using to open your AngularJS app? Check your browser's _Network_ console, does everything look correct there? If you're not sure, post some screenshots

Comment: Incredible but everything looks fine. I've added an image.

Comment: You can't just open the PHP page in your browser, that's a GET request

Comment: Oh yes, of course. However when the function is executed it doesn't work, only if i comment the line 5  `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` 
 And if i write the value on the query
 `$query = "SELECT * from repartidor WHERE id_repartidor= '4239'";`
 It is the **ONLY** way to get it work. I'm so frustrated

Comment: When I said to check your _Network_ console, I meant for you AngularJS app. You need to make sure that it is sending a POST request with the appropriate headers (eg `Content-type: application/json`) and request body (eg your `item` as JSON). Check the response that comes back for that request; what are the headers and response body? Also, I'll ask again because I think you missed it... **What URL are you using to open your AngularJS app?**

Comment: print_r($data); check its type, if you are getting as an array or an an object. you are likely getting in an array format.

Comment: @Phil Sorry, i do not have the Angular CLI installed. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy I've added that but it doesn't work neither

Comment: have you checked whats type of $data. is it array or object

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy it's an array. I think

Comment: if its array use $data['codigo'] or if its object $data->codigo in your query.

Comment: I can't believe it. SOLVED. i was trying to acces with another name to the object propertie (yes, it was an object).

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id_repartidor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id_repartidor);
$query = "SELECT * from repartidor WHERE id_repartidor= '$id_repartidor'";` THAT WORKS.

Thank you both @Phil and @prasanna for your patience!

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense given the error message

Comment: Where did I mention Angular CLI? None of what you are saying makes any sense at this stage

Comment: @Phil I'm apologize for misunderstanding, i'm newbie at Angular. However, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the lines which i modified and the code started to work:

old:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$query = "SELECT * from repartidor WHERE id_repartidor= '$data->codigo'";
```

Solved:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id_repartidor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->id_repartidor);
$query = "SELECT * from repartidor WHERE id_repartidor= '$id_repartidor'";
```